# How can I display the file name of the image I am loading in a new div?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a file input that I'm using to display image thumbnails. When you click on a thumbnail, the image appears in a separate div. That part is working fine, but I would also like the name of the file to be displayed under the larger image. I used [this great guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) for displaying multiple image thumbnails. I have two event listeners, one for load and one for click. I tried to add `document.getElementById('right').innertext=this.title;` in the click event, but it just doesn't seem to do anything.

Below is my complete code:

```html
<div id="left">
        <input id="files" type="file" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple />
        <hr>
        <div id="preview"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <img src="" id="img2" style="max-width: 500px;">
        <p></p>
    </div>

 <script>

        function previewFiles() {

            var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
            var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

            function readAndPreview(file) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
              
                reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.height = 50;
                    image.title = file.name;
                    image.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    image.src = this.result;

                    image.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    document.getElementById('img2').src = this.src;
                    document.getElementById('right').innertext=this.title;
                    }) 
                            
                    preview.appendChild(image);
                }, false);
               
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            }

            if (files) {
                [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
            }

        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

it is innerText with a capital T and you want it in the `p` tag?

```js
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files = this.files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var image = new Image();
      image.height = 50;
      image.title = file.name;
      image.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      image.src = this.result;
      image.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById('img2').src = this.src;
        document.querySelector('#right p').innerText = this.title;
      })

      preview.appendChild(image);
    }, false);

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }

}

document.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener("change",previewFiles)
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <input id="files" type="file" multiple />
  <hr>
  <div id="preview"></div>
</div>

<div id="right">
  <img src="" id="img2" style="max-width: 500px;">
  <p></p>
</div>


</script>
```

Comment: That does work, but it also makes two thumbnails of each image.

Comment: That is not my doing - i only added text